# Some questions before I install Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: software-installation

I have Windows 7 and wanting to switch to Ubuntu. So....

1. Are Skype, IMVU and Firefox available for Ubuntu?
2. I don't have a disc / USB. Does that mean I can use windows installer to download?
3. What are requirements to install? Like RAM etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, Skype, IMVU and Firefox are available.
2. You can use the Windows installer then, aka Wubi.
3. Minimum reqs are 512 MB RAM and a 1 Ghz CPU.

Comment: +1 Just to add my thought here as izx beat me to this answer(damn my slow typing) One workaround I saw was to use Wubi and then migrate it to a full install.  Hard way around but may be the only way to get a full install with no CD/USB

Comment: Shame @Trailrider I did this on an iPhone "keyboard" :P. But you are absolutely right -- that is the most practical way unless you physically pull out the hard disk and attach it to a working Linux/Ubuntu computer.

Comment: lol well I was also trying to find the place I saw the workaround so I could cite it and link to it....never did find the blasted thing either....so it wasn't just slow typing(and many typo corrections)...

Answer (score 1):

1. Skype is available on the repositories, Firefox is installed by default and IMVU is working on linux according to the IMVU forums. Just search IMVU Linux.
2. I don't know.
3. At least [384 MB of RAM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop). Search for system requirements.

Comment: what does skype is aviable on respostories mean? can you show me a screenshot of skype GUI on ubutnu? they all look different for some reason, mac for example

Comment: Skype released a 4.0 version for Linux recently. See <http://blogs.skype.com/linux/>

Comment: @Tyer Skype is available in the Ubuntu software repositories and can be installed with the included  [Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/skype/). The link is for the website but all apps listed on the site are available to be installed in Ubnuntu by just clicking the `install` button and entering your password.